# Algorithm for dividing job between people

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for some algorithm to divide job between people with as less recurrences as possible. So the general idea is to have `X` jobs to divide between `Y` people - and that would be very easy, but this should be run `Z` times and make sure that if `person-A` did `job-B` last time - that person wont do it again in new run.
For example lets have two jobs `[1,2]` and three people `[A, B, C]` and run it for 4 iterations - output could be:

```
A[1], B[2], C[]
A[1], B[2,1], C[2]
A[1,2], B[2,1], C[2,1]
A[1,2,1], B[2,1,2], C[2,1]
```

I have been messing around with some ideas, however as far as number of jobs and people increase my solutions either get stuck or produce wrong results - any idea what algorithms solve such problems?

Comment: Your idea of each person having an array of already-done-jobs seems good. When a new job comes in then just look for the first person that doesn't have the job in his array. This will make "first" people (A,B,C,...) to get more jobs than last people (...,X,Y,Z). You may shuffle the list of people before searching for a given job.

Comment: A[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2], B[], C[] will be satisfactory to you? is it right output or wrong,why so?

Comment: ii) And will A[1,2,1,2], B[2,1,2,1], C[] be satisfactory to you? is it right output or wrong,why so?

Comment: True- I forgot to mention I would like to split those jobs equally, so if someone did 3 jobs in previous run, he wont do again 3 in the next one